# What should I consider to convert between Unicode code-point and UTF8/16/32 or anything?

Tags: unicode, encoding

UTF encodings have non-character codes, and I need to handle these exceptions. I know there are plenty of libraries does this, but I think I need to know fundamental principles.

What should I care when transcode Unicode code-point into/from UTF or UCS encodings? I think each encodings have different rules, but three should be a simple principals. I want to know that.

**Update**

I posted this question because I was trying to extract a Unicode code point (not a UTF-16 character) from `NSString`. `NSString` supports only UTF-16 manner API for character handling, so I need to perform extra processing to get actual code point (which is actually meaningful). My program should

1. promote surrogate pair characters correctly
2. or prohibit them for reliable character handling.

But the problem is I am not sure that the surrogate pairs are  *the only stuffs to care* on UTF-16. I think there should be more stuffs to care, and I want to know that. And if possible, also on other encodings too. Of course, only if it's simple enough to handle. If it's incredible complex, I will just use libraries like `libICU`.

I know `libICU` will give me that features, but currently, it feels somewhat over-engineering to me. If I know the basic rules (for example, "surrogate pairs are the only things to care!"), at least prohibiting unsupported character should be very easy and simple.

Comment: Your question is rather broad. Could you try to clarify it? Maybe give an example? Code that you tried?

Comment: All the (UTF) encodings can represent the same Unicode code-points .. I don't understand what the question is asking.

Comment: Surrogate pairs are the only thing to care in UTF-16. Once you are past that and you are dealing with the semantics, depending on your program you may or may not need to care about more things (non-characters, non-assigned code points, private-use characters, etc). I would recommend sticking to ICU: it isn't overengineered; it is engineered to deal with a massively complex domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a method on NSString

```
enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:
```

where you can specify NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences as the options: and this will give you a series of NSRange values that specify the composed Unicode code points. So for most code points which fit into a single unichar (i.e. 16-bits) the NSRange will cover a single index into the NSString, but e.g. for Unicode code points of Emoji characters the NSRange will cover multiple unichars.

Comment: Is there any API to get composed code-point value from the series of `unichar`? Or should I  do it manually?

Comment: It'd probably be easiest to use the NSString stringWithCharacters:length: API to create an NSString, and you can then use enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:

Comment: If you have the Unicode code points in UTF-32 format, then you can convert them to UTF-16 (i.e. unichars) as described here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Example_UTF-16_encoding_procedure